# Is mmap() same in kernel space and user space?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

My question is not limited to `mmap()`, but all the functions (when called from userspace - a systemcall) which are used in both kernel space code and user space code. An example if I call `mmap()` from user space , that include a context switch `(SYSENTER / INT 80H)`, however that would not be needed if I call the `mmap` from kernel. My question is, is the `mmap()` function same in kernel or userspace. If it is same, is the mmap implementation manage to not execute `SYSENTER / INT 80H` if it is been called from kernel?

Comment: There's no such function in the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mmap(2)` implementation is not as illustrative because it has compatibility artefacts, but here's an example with `truncate(2)`:

1. Userspace calls into kernel space, which starts with a [specially linked](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/linux/syscalls.h#L235) function.
2. That [function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/fs/open.c#L143) calls an internal function.
3. The [internal function e.g. `do_sys_truncate()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/fs/open.c#L121) calls into an actual kernel API.
4. The [kernel API e.g. `vfs_truncate()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/fs/open.c#L69) does the heavy lifting.
5. That kernel API is what's being [exported](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/fs/open.c#L119) to the rest of the kernel code.

So, essentially, the userspace `mmap()` is just another, more complex path, to an internal kernel API that is accessible to the rest of the kernel via other, simpler path.